# Disable Chrome Autofill while using placeholders

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, autofill

I'm having some issues with google autofill for fields with placeholders. So I've tried pretty much all the solutions given at:
[Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)
, but sadly none of it works as I require.

So the idea is having a form with different fields, where some are required other aren't ( which makes Ryan Grush solution a no go ).

I've tried autocomplete="false", autocomplete="off", I've tried using the "ghost" inputs at the start of the form, tried the different ways of forcing a blank value into the fields.

I could be using javacript to hide the label (Based on Ryan Grush solution) as soon as the user starts typing but sadly by design requirements this is something that would be done only as a last resort. So I'm here hoping someone as faced something similar with Chrome and placeholders.

Comment: Please check my workaround here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill/36030236#36030236

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately
This:

```
<input autocomplete='off'>
```

And This:

```
<form autocomplete='off'>
```

Is ignored by Chrome, and I haven't found a work around as of yet...
Other browsers however like Firefox, Safari etc. Do Support it

Comment: I was stating that Chrome (Google) has chosen to ignore the autocomplete attribute, I'm aware that its obvious that it doesn't work. However thank you for pointing that out